# Why doesn't this format string work?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to use a format string which includes a } as a literal, but it's not working as I expected

```
Response.Write(String.Format("{0:d}}}", 6))
```

Outputs: `d}`

The output I'm expecting is:

```
6}
```

For some reason the } is not correctly escaped if it appears adjacent to a non-escaped }.

Furthermore, this line of code actually throws an exception!

```
Response.Write(String.Format("{0:D}}}", SqlDbType.Int))
```

The expected output from that is: `8}` (As the enum constant for SqlDbType.Int is 8)

This problem is occuring in real life code - the examples above are just to illustrate the point. How am I supposed to format text strings that contain curly braces?

Comment: This [works as expected on ideone](http://ideone.com/NLKeb9).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: ideone implements Mono. There's a "[bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/12/26/50978.aspx)" in the .NET implementation.

Comment: @McGarnagle: No, it's [not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a "[bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/12/26/50978.aspx)". You need to say:

```
String.Format("{0}{1:d}{2}", "{", 6, "}")
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String.Format("{0:d'}'}", 6)    in C#
```

or the following may work in VB.Net ...

```
String.Format("{0:d\}}", 6)    in VB.net
```

Comment: This throws an exception in VB.Net. I assume it's for c#?

Comment: ahhh yes.. what is the exception?